# Create a new column based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
name<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac","d","d","d")
value<-c(4,5,6,7,3,4,8,9,8)
week<-c(31,31,32,31,31,35,32,33,35)
c<-data.frame(name,value,week)
```

What I want is to create a new column with the sum of the values that have the same name and then belong to the same week. This should be the result:

```
    name value week sum
1   ab     4   31   9
2   ab     5   31   9
3   ab     6   32   6
4   ac     7   31  10
5   ac     3   31  10
6   ac     4   35   4
7    d     8   32   8
8    d     9   33   9
9    d     8   35   8
```

Comment: How about `c$sum <- with(c, ave(value, list(name, week), FUN = sum))`

Comment: Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: No duplication with the link above as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using a for-loop

```
c$sum <- rep(NA,nrow(c))
for(i in 1:nrow(c)) {
  c$sum[i] <- sum(subset(c, name==c[i,'name'] & week==c[i,'week'])[,'value'])
}
```

Result:

```
  name value week sum
 1   ab     4   31   9
 2   ab     5   31   9
 3   ab     6   32   6
 4   ac     7   31  10
 5   ac     3   31  10
 6   ac     4   35   4
 7    d     8   32   8
 8    d     9   33   9
 9    d     8   35   8
```